# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Razor - Authorize

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying out asp.net core 2 razor pages.  If someone tries to access a page and they are not logged in or are in the correct role, I should not give them access to that page.

what is the appropriate way to limit the person's access to the page?

I would think that I would put some type of an attribute in the page's view model class, but that does not seem to work.  I've tried to add attributes to the various methods and the class with no luck.

Comment: Nevermind.  I must have been doing something wrong.  I applied the Authorize attribute to the pagemodel class and now it seems to be acting like I would expect.  I guess I was doing something stupid before.

Comment: the `Authorize` attribute should go on controllers or methods of controllers. Or do you mean "Razor Pages"?

Comment: I'm trying the Asp.NET Core 2 Razor Pages.  I thought I had this problem solved, but I was wrong.  Its a strange problem.

Answer (score 8):

To use the authorize attribute you can decorate the `PageModel` with the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

For example:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also setup authorization under the options of the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/MembersOnly");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");

        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Pages/Admin", "Admins"); // with policy
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Pages/Admin/Login"); // excluded page

        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToFolder("/Public"); // just for completeness
    });
```

The `AuthorizeFolder` will restrict access to the entire folder, whereas the `AuthorizePage` would be restricting access based on the individual page. The `AllowAnonymousToFolder` and `AllowAnonymousToPage` doing the opposite, accordingly.

For specific documentation on the above, **as of today, the documentation is still being completed.** However, you can read about the progress of it and track it here https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4281

Otherwise, you can have a more general read about [Authorization in ASP.NET Core on the official Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/).